# no changes to deploy android studio

Tags: android-studio

When I make changes to my application, specifically in the values.xml file and run the app, the changes are not reflected. I tried the solutions I've found how to disable Instant run, clean the application and re-run but nothing works. I am with Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: If the instant run does not deploy any changes made, I usually stop execution, clean project and re - run. If not try uninstalling the application from your Android device (or emulator) and try again.